# Excel macro search for values in a specific arrangement, possible?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my dilemma, I need to parse a series of 606 weeks worth of Billboard 200 charts for the position of 36 different albums.  Here's what I've got so far...

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_tgNfDq0kXAakR5eHZ3bzJQVkk/edit?usp=sharing

Billboard just redid their website, so now Excel's webquery returns a very pretty and clean table.  I created two formulas in columns A and B of my worksheet, A has the list of relevant dates (specifically every Saturday from 8/18/2001 until this week), and B makes hyperlinks to the charts based on the dates.  The rest of the chart is color-coded for the benefit of my advisors, who will also be reviewing the sheet.

I've also manually webqueried the first chart, dated 2001-08-18, into its own worksheet.  This worksheet hasn't been touched - its exactly what the webquery returned.

As you can see, the table spans to column G, and each entry takes up 3 rows.  My focus is on columns C and D.  Column D's rows for each entry are (top-to-bottom) Title, Artist, and Imprint|Label.  The first row in Column C for each entry contains that week's position from 1 to 200.  The pattern that emerges is that every 3rd row starting with 4 (so 7, 10, 13...) contains a position and album title (col C & D, resp.), and every 3rd cell starting with 5 contains an artist.

I'm going to try to explain what I'm imagining in plain English, but be forewarned that this may fail miserably.

So the macro would take two cells as input (can they even take input?), album title and corresponding artist.  This input should tell the macro both the string stored in each cell and the location - e.g, E1, C2 - of said cell.  The macro should loop through each URL in column A from row 3 to 608, querying the URL into a new sheet.  This new sheet should be made active, and then every 3rd row starting with 4 should be searched sequentially for the album title string.  Upon finding a match, the cell one row beneath the matching query cell should be compared to the artist name string.  Should both strings match the content of their corresponding query cells, the number (from 1 to 200) in column C and the same row as the matching album title cell should be copied to the cell in the 'bb200' sheet corresponding to the URL queried and the album title searched.  The loop should now recur on the next URL in the sequence.  In the event no match is found (the album didn't chart that week, or BB returned a wonky table), the corresponding cell should be left blank.  The macro should exit once the list of URLs is exhausted.

My problem is twofold:  first off, is my thought process regarding the macro fundamentally sound?  And second-but-most-importantly, I haven't the faintest clue where to even start writing this in VBA.  I have studied Java, C, and most recently C++ (OpenGL, specifically).  I'm totally unfamiliar with the VBA syntax and API, and frankly, my time on this is far too short to sit down and formally learn the language.  After this, I plan on doing so in short order, but this assignment is due Monday and I had no idea how massive an undertaking it was going to end up being.

FOR THE RECORD, the macro is not the assignment, but the data to be collected is integral to completing it.  To those curious, the assignment is to produce a complete rough draft of my senior thesis by Monday.  This data will be used to create several graphs that my advisors have instructed me to include with my writing.  The paper itself is already written based on simply reading each album's sales performance off the site.

You'd be helping me go above-and-beyond, as most of the other graduating seniors are turning in some seriously half-baked graphical representation.  The only other student that went this far invented an instrument and provided schematics and autoCAD drawings.  However, on that I digress.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: I was going to suggest investigating whether Billboard had an API for accessing this data and indeed they used to. Unfortunately it has been disabled - see [here](http://developer.billboard.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  They nixed the API in favor for getting rid of nasty code.  Their website used to have all manner of eyecandy, interactive graphs and the like.  Very pretty, but not conducive to scraping implementations, thus the need for the API.  Honestly, I'm glad they made the change because who doesn't love standards compliance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should get you about 90%.  The only thing this won't do is the web query.

For that part, I propose that you use the macro recorder to do a web query, and then post that code in a revision and we'll add it in and tailor it to your needs. You've gotta do *some* work on this :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMacro()
Dim inputVal As String
Dim artistCell As Range
Dim artistName As String
Dim albumCell As Range
Dim albumName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("thesisData")
Dim r As Long 'this will be our row iterator variable
Dim hLink As String 'string for each hyperlink in the iteration
Dim wsNew As Worksheet 'this will be used when we create new worksheets
Dim foundRange As Range 'this is how we will locate the album
Dim weekRank As Long 'weekly rank from column C


On Error GoTo InvalidRange  'This error handling is for the input box, to trap invalid arguments.'
'Use an input box to capture the cell address'
inputVal = InputBox("Please enter the cell location containing the ARTIST name", "Input Range")
Set artistCell = Range(inputVal)  'set a Range variable for the artist'
artistName = artistCell.Value  'string variable for artist name'

inputVal = vbNullString 'clear out the inputVal'
'Use an input box again...'
inputVal = InputBox("Please enter the cell location containing the ALBUM name", "Input Range")
Set albumCell = Range(inputVal)  'set a Range variable for the song cell'
albumName = albumCell.Value  'string for song name'
On Error GoTo 0

For r = 3 To 608  'iterate over rows 3 to 608
    hLink = ws.Cells(1, r).Value

    'Add a new sheet after the last sheet in this file'

    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    wsNew.Name = Format(ws.Cells(r, 2).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

    '''' add VBA for web query, here.'
    ''''
    '''' try using the macro recorder and we can tweak it to your needs.'
    ''''
    ''''
    ''''

    'Rather than looping over all the cells in web query...'
    Do
        'Use the FIND method to look for matching album title in column D.'
        ' this uses exact text match, non-case-sensitive.
        Dim fnd

        Set foundRange = wsNew.Columns(4).Find(What:=albumName, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            'if we've found a match, then just offset by 1 row and check against artist name'
            If foundRange.Offset(1, 0) = artistName Then
                'likewise, just offset the foundRange cell by -1 columns to get the weekly rank'
                weekRank = foundRange.Offset(0, -1)

                'At this point I'm not sure what cell you want to put this value in, '
                ' but I think you want row designated by "r" and the column of the '
                ' album name, so we can do that like this:

                ws.Cells(r, albumCell.Column).Value = weekRank

            End If
        End If
    Loop While Not foundRange Is Nothing


Next

Exit Sub 'before error handling
InvalidRange:     'error handling

MsgBox inputVal & " is not a valid range", vbCritical, "Error!"

End Sub
```

Good luck!

**Edit** this also assumes that there is only going to be one match in each web query. In the event there is more than one, it would only return the last match. That seems like a safe assumption given the nature of the data, but if that's not the case, let me know and I can tweak it.

Comment: Wow...this is pretty amazing, not gonna lie.  That being said, right after I posted the question, I got to work learning enough VBA to make a working script.  My latest test is running now, and _appears_ to be working.  If it ends up doing what I need, I'll post it here, if not, I'm abandoning it and giving your code a try.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, I appreciate the warning.  I'm admittedly a novice programmer, despite finishing up my degree including Comp Sci Minor (emphasis on MINOR, as in I've only taken 5 hardcore programming classes) so I don't blame anyone for insta-downvoting the novel I wrote on the basis of "stfu noob."  That being said, it simply makes me appreciate your assistance that much more =).

Comment: no problem. you sound genuinely interested in learning whereas often times I think people just expect someone else to solve all their problems. Once you break down your particular problem it is pretty straightforward: Iterate over a column of data, and for each row in the iteration, 1) create new sheet with web query, 2) find some matching parameters in the new sheet, 3) return some values corresponding to those matches to the original table. Not tremendously difficult, but it would seem pretty daunting to someone unfamiliar with VBA.

Comment: @DavidZemens: +1 for the effort, the solution and the help. Note however, that I suggested an edit that removes the warning about the question. While a valid concern, this is not part of the answer, but rather a comment to the question.

Comment: @PeterAlbert thanks on both accounts. i'll try to editorialize less next time :)

Comment: I know this was from months ago, but going through your syntax actually served as a crash course in the finer points of VBA scripting, so I owe you a lot for the A- I got on my senior thesis.