# Sorting names into respective columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Data sheet. Let's say that Column "A" has a bunch of breeds of dogs: Lab, Beagle, Golden, and Poodle.

Column "B" has their names. There are lots of dogs all of composed of these four breeds, all with different names.

Column "C" has their location: New York, Texas, Louisiana, and Florida

What I'd like to do is write a script that searches Column "A" for all Labs that live in New York. Once the script finds these dogs, it grabs their name, and puts their name in a column on a separate worksheet.

I need to accomplish this for all the dogs. The seperate worksheet should have lists for New York, Texas, Louisiana, and Florida, with all the dogs names below it. I plan on color coding the dog names based on breed.

I was thinking I could use the `Find` method but, I honestly haven't worked with VBA too much, and my googling hasn't been too successful. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need to search column A for each breed if all you need is Name and Locations??? Do you mean you need a Column for each location for each breed with Names in the rows?

Comment: Because I'll be color coding them based on breed.

Comment: I would definitely use conditional formatting for color coding based on breed instead of VBA. Will the Second sheet be blank or already have the columns with the Locations set up?

Comment: Is not autofilter an option??? Or maybe pivot table???

Comment: The whole point of this is that the data tab will be changing a lot. As this tab changes, so will other worksheets change in response to the data tab changing...

Comment: Here is an example of using the `Find` method inside a Loop. That's what you'll need to do, probably with an additional loop or so.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725383/1467082

Comment: Alternatively, I'd probably use autofilter in a macro for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Tweak as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestDogs()
Dim dogBreed As String
Dim dogName As String
Dim dogLoc As String
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim arrDogs() As String
Dim i As Long

Set wsMaster = Worksheets("List") '<modify as needed.'
wsMaster.Activate
Range("A1").Activate
dogBreed = InputBox("Enter the breed", "Dog Breed", "Lab")
dogLoc = InputBox("Enter the location", "Dog location", "New York")

Set rng = Range("A1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))
Range("A1").Activate
Do
    'use the .Find method to look for dog breed in column A'

    Set rngFound = rng.Find(What:=dogBreed, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        rngFound.Activate
        'Check to see if the Location matches:'
        If rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value = dogLoc Then
            dogName = rngFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
            'If so, then add to the array'
            ReDim Preserve arrDogs(i)
            arrDogs(i) = dogName
            i = i + 1
            If i >= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, dogBreed) - 1 Then Exit Do
        End If
    Else: Exit Do
    End If

'Loop, the counter variable "i" will exit this loop when necessary.
Loop

If UBound(arrDogs) >= 0 Then
    'Add a new sheet if any matches were found
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=wsMaster)

    With wsNew
        'Give the sheet a meaningful name.'
        .Name = Left(dogBreed & " - " & dogLoc, 31)
        'Print out the dog names on the new sheet'
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").Offset(UBound(arrDogs), 0)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrDogs)
    End With
Else:
    MsgBox "No dogs matching criteria [Breed =" & dogBreed & "] and [Location =" & dogLoc & "]", vbInformation

End If
End Sub
```